# Converting a specific JS to generalized jQuery script (example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, checkbox

I am much more familiar with JS than jQuery but it looks like I need to expand my knowledge of the latter to achieve what I am trying to do.

I have this code: which has a button that toggles between black,green, and red and checks neither box, box1, or box 2 respectively.

Example in JS: [JS demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7Tjvj/1/)

```
var colors = ["green", "red", "black"];

function setColor(el) {
   el.colorIdx = el.colorIdx || 0;
   el.style.color = colors[el.colorIdx++ % colors.length];
document.getElementById('box1').checked = el.style.color == 'green';
document.getElementById('box2').checked = el.style.color == 'red';
}
```

But I need to make the script more generalized so that it will work for any button/checkbox.  This is what I have started so far, but I don't know how to combine it with the color properites like the JS.

[jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/LKDCM/1/)

```
$("input").on('click', function () {
    $("[name^=" + this.value + 1 + "]").attr('checked', true)
    $("[name^=" + this.value + 2 + "]").attr('checked', true) 
})
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/7Tjvj/3/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to go with jQuery to accomplish this. Here is a pure-JS solution, I wrap your checkbox/button sets in a `<div class="color-set">` for an easy way to allow more and then use the `data-color` attribute to set which color *index* (could easily check against text too) it is for whether we set the checkbox.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/dKE5X/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="color-set">
    <input type="checkbox" data-color="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" data-color="1" />
    <input type="button" value="box" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var colors = ["green", "red", "black"];

function setColor() {
    this.colorIdx = (this.colorIdx || 0) % colors.length;
    this.style.color = colors[this.colorIdx];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.checkboxes.length; i++) {
        this.checkboxes[i].checked = this.colorIdx == this.checkboxes[i].getAttribute('data-color');
    }

    this.colorIdx++;
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var colorSet = document.getElementsByClassName('color-set');

    for (var i = 0; i < colorSet.length; i++) {
        var button = colorSet[i].querySelector('input[type=button]');
        button.checkboxes = colorSet[i].querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        button.addEventListener('click', setColor);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this solution runs into the same problem as the first.  I think that's because I did not clearly explain myself.  The reason I was thinking jQuery was because I plan to have many buttons with 2 corresponding checkboxes.  So the generalized code would look at the value of the button and act on the checkboxes with ID's of value1 and value2.

Comment: Yes, look at the jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/dKE5X/1/), I have demonstrated multiple buttons/checkboxes :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generalized option using jQuery:

Content:

```
<div class='example-container'>
    <input type="checkbox"  />
    <input type="checkbox"  />
    <input type="button"  value="box" />
</div>
```

Code:

```
function colorCycle(container, colors) {
  colors = colors || ["black", "green", "red"];
  var button = container.find(':button');
  var checkboxes = container.find(':checkbox');
  var index = 0;

  function setIndex(newIndex) {
    index = newIndex;
    checkboxes.attr('checked', false);
    if (index > 0)
      $(checkboxes[index - 1]).attr('checked', true)

    button.css('color', colors[index]);
  }

  button.click(function () {
    setIndex((index + 1) % (checkboxes.length + 1));
  });

  // Optional bidirectional support:
  checkboxes.change(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    if (!checkbox.attr('checked')) {
      setIndex(0);
    } 
    else {
      setIndex(checkboxes.index(checkbox) + 1);
    }
  });
}

$(function () {
  colorCycle($('.example-container'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmyfr/

It has less dependencies on the HTML elements and supports any number of checkboxes and bidirectional updates.

Comment: This seems to work well except that I plan to have multiple buttons with 2 corresponding check boxes.  With this solution, I would need to separately div each grouping and add a corresponding colorCycle.  My preference is that the jQuery would look at the value of the button and act on the checkboxes with the IDs of value1 and value2.  Also, when the cycle only works for the checkboxes the first time through.  When you cycle back to black and then the rest of the colors, the checkboxes remain unchecked.